# Gatling 2 : How to change directory location of the scala classes

Tags: class, scala, compilation, location, gatling

How can I change the location of the compiled scala files. Currently the files are stored in $GATLING_HOME/target/classes.

I thought the option "--simulations-binaries-folder" would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"--simulations-binaries-folder" is used for forcing Gatling to search there for pre-compiled classes.

Check out gatling.conf file for the property named "gatling.core.directory.binaries". You can either override it directly in the file, or pass a System property with this name.

Comment: I have change the gatling.conf and set the property: gatling { core { directory { binaries = '/app/performance' ... Starting gatling again, still got an error; java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. I was expecting that is compiles the scala files again and put the classes here.

Comment: You probably have to clean Zinc cache contained in target in order to re-trigger the compiler. Or touch all your files.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the Zinc cache and classes directory. Start gatling... same error

Comment: That's a bug. Let me fix it.

Comment: Fixed, see: https://github.com/excilys/gatling/issues/1713. You'll have to grab a snapshot though.